# Application of Cramer's Rule on linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some trouble with the following linear algebra question on Cramer's rule: An explanation for your choice of answer please.

> Determine whether Cramer's Rule can be applied on the following system
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}x_1\cos(u) - x_2\sin(u) = 1\\x_1\sin(u)+x_2\cos(u)=-3\end{cases}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! this site uses latex for math notations, please use it. Also, it is highly recommended to show some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: Well, what is the condition in Cramer's rule (i.e. what needs to be satisfied for you to be allowed to apply it?)

Comment: It depends on which are the indeterminates and which are the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), the square coefficient matrix $A$ (for the system $AX=B$ with as many equations as unknowns) has to have a *nonzero determinant*.

What is $A$ for your system? Check its determinant.

Note: a nonzero determinant guarantees a unique solution (given by Cramer's rule).

Comment: Why would the OP check that the determinant is $0$ when it is in fact not?

Comment: Thanks, my mistake! (edited)

Comment: Aaaah... Thanks... So finding the determinant of this coefficient matrix A by cofactor expansion along the first row, gives us (\cos\theta)(\cos\theta) + ((-\sin\theta)(-\sin\theta)) = \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1 $\therefore determinant of A is nonzero and Cramer's rule can be used. True. p.s. I don't know how to use latex. Will check it out soon.

Comment: That's correct!